# google maps zoom in and zoom out android

Tags: android, google-maps

### I have the code where i have disabled the movement

**code:**

```
yourmap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

### What i am trying to achieve:

- At present i am able to zoom in and zoom out using map controles
- How can i use my fingers to zoom in and zoom out
- but keeping map movements disabled

***is this achievable ?***

**fragment in xml::**

```
  <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not set  `googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false)`. Instead, use individual methods to set desired gestures enabled and disabled.
Such as

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Perfect ... ! i don't have enough points to give [+1] too ;) ... thanks

Comment: I want to set maximum zoom level. This code is just enable and disable things. Like zoom control, rotate gesture...Do you have code which set maximum zoom level?

Answer (score 1):

add this method to your map object

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```